# Wordpress, how to redirect from one form page to another?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

How can I pass variables from one page to another in Wordpress?

I'm now trying to build form on one page, and if user press button [NEXT>], form submits, 
and redirect `wp_redirect( $final_url ); exit;` 
user to another page with continuing form.

I'm using POST method for form.

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post" id="multiForm" >  
    <label for="client">Klients: *</label><input id="client" type="text" name="client" placeholder="Reg.nr | Pk.kods" pattern="[0-9]{10,12}" title="Jābut vismāz 10 cipariem!" required="required" maxlength="12" /></br>
    <label for="selector1">Darījuma vadītājs: *</label>
    <select id="selector1" name="darvad" required >
        <option value="">-Dar. vadītājs-</option>
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT Vards_Uzvards, Tables_ID FROM users";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);  // return an object, not ARRAY_N
if ($results) {
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo "<option value = '".$row->Tables_ID."'>".$row->Vards_Uzvards."</option>"; 
}}
    echo "</select></br>";                          
?>
<label for="owcafind"><a href="<?php echo site_url('/sample-page/owca/'); ?>" target="_blank">Meklēt OWCA kodu:</a> *</label><input id="owcafind" type="text" name="owca" placeholder="OWCA Kods (8)" pattern="[0-9]{5,8}" title="Jābut vismāz 5 cipariem!" maxlength="8"  /></br>

<label for="ldrive">Mape L diskā:</label><input id="ldrive" type="text" name="ldrive" placeholder="Mape L diskā" value="" /></br>
<label for="sanemt">Saņemšanas datums:</label><input id="sanemt" type="date" name="sanemt" placeholder="Saņemšanas datums" value="" required /></br>
</fieldset>

<label for="comment">Komentārs:</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea></br>

<input type="submit" value="NEXT>" />
</form>
```

AND PHP Code in the same page:

```
<!-- START PHP POST -->
<?php   

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
//<< Get variables from form in tsales_funnel
    $darvad = esc_sql($_POST['darvad']);
    $starp = esc_sql(left($_POST['owca'], 5));
    $owc =  esc_sql($_POST['owca']);
    $ldrive = esc_sql($_POST['ldrive']);
    $currentuser = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
    $sanemt = esc_sql($_POST['sanemt']);

// /Get variables >>

//<< SQL STATMENT tsales_funnel
$sql_fun = "INSERT INTO tsales_funnel (Darijuma_Vaditajs, Sanems_date, Starpnieks, OWCA, Link_L, user, adddate)
VALUES ('".$darvad."','".$sanemt."','".$starp."','".$owc."','".$ldrive."','".$currentuser."',now())
";
// SQL STATMENT tsales_funnel >>

// Insert values to tsales_funnel
$wpdb->query($sql_fun);
//------------ Add to GLOBAL variable just inserted ID--------------------
$GLOBAL['Funnelid'] = $wpdb->insert_id; 

$final_url = site_url('/add-product');
wp_redirect( $final_url ); exit;            
} 

?>
```

I'm trying use `$GLOBAL['Funnelid'] = $wpdb->insert_id;` , but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass this parameter in url. Something like:

```
wp_redirect( $final_url . "?Funnelid=" . $wpdb->insert_id );
```

Or store variable in session or save in cookies.

Comment: Is there some difference between session and cookies? I know, that cookies saves in user computer, but sessions in server. What do you think, what is the better solve for saving last inserted id?

Comment: It depends from situation and data. But yes, if you save data in session - it will be stored on server side and it is more safe way.

Comment: I'm trying to use after form $_SESSION['lastFunnelid'] = $wpdb->insert_id; AND in redirected page use echo $_SESSION['lastFunnelid']; but it doesn't work(

Comment: Probably session is not started by default. 
Try add next code before using session vars in both scripts:

`if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}`

Comment: But i thought that wordpress by default has sessions in all pages, or not?

Comment: Hm - never used it in Wordpress before, but after some research I see that yes - Wordpress is not using session. Just some different plugins using sessions. So - you have to test and start session for your code.

Comment: So, I need to insert -> if (!session_id()) { session_start(); } <- only in pages, where i need to use this session variables? or just add to header and it will be in all pages, because of function <?php get_header(); ?> ?

Comment: If you have only 2 pages where you are using sessions - probably if will be enough add code only for those 2 pages. But if you have plans to use sessions more - then sure - better setup it globally.